# Advanced Dojo query

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
store = Observable(new Memory({data: data}));


chart.addSeries("Load Cell 0", new StoreSeries(store, { query: { load_cell_id:0 }}, "kn"));
```

How would I go about doing a more advanced query with the Store Series?

For the above i need all 'load_cell_id = 0' and 'date_time < 12345' or other time stamp.

At the moment i can only get load_cell_id:0 to work.

Answer (score 1):

As with `dojo/store/Memory` you can use a function as a query ([source](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/object-store)):

```
store.query(function(product){
    return product.price < 10;
}).forEach(function(shoe){
    // called for each match
});
```

See my answer to [Is it possible to filter data in a dgrid like you can in a datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010731/is-it-possible-to-filter-data-in-a-dgrid-like-you-can-in-a-datagrid-if-so-how) for more [complex example](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/7gnFd/). Alternatively, in the case you need bad ass querying, there is [Resource Query Language](https://github.com/kriszyp/rql) as I mentioned in the answer to [How to query a dgrid on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207364/how-to-query-a-dgrid-on-multiple-columns) (example code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/VjJBT/)).

Comment: I cant quite work out where to put that when creating a new StoreSeries ?

Comment: Well I have no experience with that, but I would say `new StoreSeries(store, { query: function(item) { /* return true or false */} }, "kn")`.