# how to have a working grid displaying data source from ajax with the grid?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, dgrid

As I have learned the tutorial about dgrid(a new dojo grid),I have learned the example code.
Let me pick one to list here:

```
require(["dgrid/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Grid){
var data = [
    { first: "Bob", last: "Barker", age: 89 },
    { first: "Vanna", last: "White", age: 55 },
    { first: "Pat", last: "Sajak", age: 65 }
];

var grid = new Grid({
    columns: {
        first: "First Name",
        last: "Last Name",
        age: "Age"
    }
}, "grid");
grid.renderArray(data);
});
```

I Just want to know if we can displaying data from Ajax data source. How to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dgrid/OnDemandGrid`](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid) together with [`dojo/store/JsonRest`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/store/JsonRest) or [`dojo/store/Memory`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/store/Memory).

You can find a working example in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010731/is-it-possible-to-filter-data-in-a-dgrid-like-you-can-in-a-datagrid-if-so-how/12198356#12198356) to *Is it possible to filter data in a dgrid like you can in a datagrid?*: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/7gnFd/